# CSS page number for @media print

Tags: javascript, css, printing

510/5000
I would like to know if there is any alternative to showing numbers on the pages when printing with css / js. Without using any library, I found some ways but it did not work.

tais como:

```
#pageFooter:after {
    counter-increment: page;
    content: counter(page);
}
```

I saw that there are some problems with Chorme / Firefox browsers. But I wanted to know if there are any alternatives for those who do not use library.

obs: There are several questions in the stack, but all of them are old and without a correct answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, CSS print styles are still poorly implemented across most browsers. There may not be a universal fix.

Comment: is there any for chrome? @Blazemonger